# Go - How do you change the value of a pointer parameter?

Tags: go, reflection

In Golang, is it possible to change a pointer parameter's value to something else?

For example,

```
func main() {
    i := 1
    test(&i)
}

func test(ptr interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(ptr)

    fmt.Println(v.CanSet()) // false
    v.SetInt(2) // panic
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3OwGYrb-W-

Is it possible to have `test()` change `i` to point to another value 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for,
but yes you can change a pointer's value to something else.
The [code below](https://play.golang.org/p/mRjTWWkI-O) will print 2 and 3:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 1

    testAsAny(&i)
    fmt.Println(i)

    testAsInt(&i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func testAsAny(ptr interface{}) {
    *ptr.(*int) = 2
}

func testAsInt(i *int) {
    *i = 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's now to set the value using the reflect package. The key point is to set the pointer's element, not the pointer itself.

```
func test(ptr interface{}) {
  v := reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Elem()
  v.SetInt(2)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/wKeT2QtaIm)

Note that the reflect package is not needed for this specific example as shown in another answer.

Comment: This also works! Turns out I should read The Laws of Reflection.